# RightToLeft layout property for custom progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is the link to Custom Progress Bar What I am looking for is to add Right To Left Layout Property for custom progress bar. Can anyone help me in writing property for Right To Left Layout in C#

[Custom Progress Bar](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Custom-Colored-ProgressBar-a68b61de#content)

Comment: Try changing the start point and end point

Comment: should I reverse them in code End Point as Start and Start Point as End Where to modify it in code

Comment: I am not sure that might work but give it a try

Comment: tried but no luck

Comment: You cannot change position or start position of any progress bar of .NET. But if you only and only need reverse progress bar, you can create a user control and use Shape and draw properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option, you can change coordinates of painted shapes in `OnPaint` method this way:

```
protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.RightToLeft == System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes)
        e.Graphics.Transform = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, Width, 0);

    //draw background and progress

    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

    //draw image
    //draw text
    //draw border
}
```

In following image, you can see a left to right and a right to left progress bar:

[image]

Comment: What errors? I used the same code which you shared.

Comment: Yes but its for .Net Framework 3.5 I want the same code for .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: I tested it again, It works properly with .NET 2.0 and 3.5. The only change which I made was removing `System.Linq`.

Comment: VS2008 Windows CE .Net Framework 2.0 Same code falls into errors

Comment: The code which you shared in the question is not for .NET compact. It's for .NET framework 2 and 3.5.

Comment: yes I know I am using same code for Compact framework and it results into error

Comment: I'm not answering a .NET Compact. The answer is dedicated to .NET 2.0/3.5 like the code you shared in the answer :) If you are asking for a convert to .NET Compact, I suggest closing this question and asking a new question about converting that code to .NET Compact. Keep each post about a single topic :)

Comment: By the way, I see you have not accepted any answer in your previous questions or even not voted any answer ever. You can vote for useful answers by click on up arrow near the answer. Also you can accept and vote for answers which solved what has been asked in answer. Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about stackoverflow and then spend some times to verify the answers for your previous questions :)